# Postgresql; Max value from column A depending on column B

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty new to SQL.

I have a table like this:

| id | document_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | success | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | 1 | fail | 02-01-2022 |
| 3 | 1 | success | 03-01-2022 |
| 4 | 2 | error | 01-01-2022 |
| 5 | 2 | success | 02-01-2022 |
| 6 | 2 | error | 03-01-2022 |
| 7 | 3 | fail | 01-01-2022 |
| 8 | 3 | fail | 02-01-2022 |
| 9 | 4 | success | 01-01-2022 |
| 10 | 4 | fail | 02-01-2022 |

I need to get latest date for every document for every status

| document_id | success_date | fail_date | error_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-01-2022 | 02-01-2022 | null |
| 2 | 02-01-2022 | null | 03-01-2022 |
| 3 | null | 02-01-2022 | null |
| 4 | 01-01-2022 | 02-01-2022 | null |

My current query below, how to improve it to get the result I want?

```
SELECT
    document_id,
    status,
    date
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    document_id,
    status,
    date
ORDER BY
    document_id,
    date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtered aggregation for this:

```
select document_id, 
       max("date") filter (where status = 'success') as success_date,
       max("date") filter (where status = 'fail') as fail_date,
       max("date") filter (where status = 'error') as error_date
from the_table
group by document_id
order by document_id;
```